# How can I link Systick_Handler() to the exception of Systick？

Tags: c, arm, stm32, interrupt, soc

I am doing some programming on Arm Cortex M0 by C without any built-in libraries. I want to make a timer based on Systick and there is my code.

```
void systick_enable(void){
  SYSTICK_BASE -> CSR = 0x0003;
}

void systick_disable(void){
  SYSTICK_BASE -> CSR &= !(0x0003);
}

void systick_clear(void){
  SYSTICK_BASE -> CVR = 0x0000;
}

void systick_init(uint32_t reload_val) {
    systick_clear();
    SYSTICK_BASE->RVR = reload_val;
    ICSR[0] =1<<26;
    systick_enable();
}

void Systick_Handler(void){
  time++;
}
```

And here is my main function

```
int main(void) {
  int time = 0;
  systick_init(40000);
}
```

This code invokes the Systick to count down from 40000, but when it becomes 0, I want it to jump to `Systick_Handler()`.

I don't know how to invoke `Systick_Handler()`. I have set the Systick exception to be pended, but how can I let the program run `Systick_Handler()` when exception happens?

I have read some example codes of microcontroller unit like STM32, it seems that they claim a `Systick_Handler()` without calling it in main funciton， how does it work? Is it because of the build-in libraries? Should I write one?

Comment: Maybe your initialization should stop/disable the timer first: if it is *already* enabled could avoid updating the RVR

Comment: Exception handlers are not called from other functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use libraries, well even if you do, you want the ARM Architectural Reference Manual which for cortex-ms is either armv6-m, armv7-m or the armv8-m flavors.  But for this the armv6-m is plenty.  In general you need the Technical Reference Manual for the core, so say cortex-m0 for example.  Basically everything you need to know is between those documents, each cortex-m based chip will have a TRM and ARM from arm for the core that that chip company purchased to put in their chip.

vectors.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset             //  1 reset
.word hang              //  2 NMI
.word hang              //  3 hard fault
.word hang              //  4 Reserved
.word hang              //  5 Reserved
.word hang              //  6 Reserved
.word hang              //  7 Reserved
.word hang              //  8 Reserved
.word hang              //  9 Reserved
.word hang              // 10 Reserved
.word hang              // 11 SVCall
.word hang              // 12 Reserved
.word hang              // 13 Reserved
.word hang              // 14 PendSV
.word systick_handler   // 15 SysTick

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
#define UART0BASE 0x4000C000
#define STK_CSR 0xE000E010
#define STK_RVR 0xE000E014
#define STK_CVR 0xE000E018
#define STK_MASK 0x00FFFFFF

void systick_handler ( void )
{
    PUT32(UART0BASE+0x00,0x55);
}
int notmain ( void )
{
    PUT32(STK_CSR,4);
    PUT32(STK_RVR,10000-1);
    PUT32(STK_CVR,0);
    PUT32(STK_CSR,7);
    return(0);
}
```

memmap

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 vectors.s -o vectors.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.elf -T memmap vectors.o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf notmain.bin -O binary
```

This one is written to be run on qemu. (uart address is specific to target/chip, and in qemu you will find you can often cheat and not have to check for tx buffer space being available)

```
qemu-system-arm -M lm3s811evb -m 8K -nographic -kernel notmain.bin
```

and then for me it is ctrl-a then x to stop it.  I get UUUUUUUUU on that terminal and it will repeat until you stop.

The basic answer to your question is, and is already answered by others.

```
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset             //  1 reset
.word hang              //  2 NMI
.word hang              //  3 hard fault
.word hang              //  4 Reserved
.word hang              //  5 Reserved
.word hang              //  6 Reserved
.word hang              //  7 Reserved
.word hang              //  8 Reserved
.word hang              //  9 Reserved
.word hang              // 10 Reserved
.word hang              // 11 SVCall
.word hang              // 12 Reserved
.word hang              // 13 Reserved
.word hang              // 14 PendSV
.word systick_handler   // 15 SysTick
```

This is my vector table.  The arm documents tell you the exact makeup of this
first part of the vector table.  Beyond this it is some number of dozens of interrupts.  The interrupts are very specific to the chip which is from companies like ST or NXP or others, and has nothing to do with ARM so they are not involved other than providing dozens of interrupt signals.

For the assembly language you need to use .thumb_func for gnu assembler, or
.type ... function.  Can look at the assembly language output from gcc to see that they tend to put both, you can pick one or the other  (otherwise your vector table will not work or you will fall into some bad hacks that folks use rather than do it right)

```
.thumb_func
reset:
...
.thumb_func
hang:
```

With this architecture you do not need to wrap an interrupt handler with code to save state.  If the compiler conforms to a matching abi, then you can simply put the C function name of the handler in the table directly, as shown above.

The bootstrap and linker script tend to be married, well almost have to be, and then for whatever reason folks tend to then overload them with library stuff making the linker script, the bootstrap, and the libraries being married and inseparable.

Typically the handler at least the one used by reset, is in flash.  So cannot be changed/registered runtime.

Some cores, but not all, have a VTOR register where you can, with rules, change the location of the vector table used by the logic.  And that means you can, yes, use another flash address if you are having field upgradable applications, but you can also point it at sram in most implementations, allowing for runtime changes.

Or you could do something like this:

stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset             //  1 reset
.word hang              //  2 NMI
.word hang              //  3 hard fault
.word hang              //  4 Reserved
.word hang              //  5 Reserved
.word hang              //  6 Reserved
.word hang              //  7 Reserved
.word hang              //  8 Reserved
.word hang              //  9 Reserved
.word hang              // 10 Reserved
.word hang              // 11 SVCall
.word hang              // 12 Reserved
.word hang              // 13 Reserved
.word hang              // 14 PendSV
.word 0x20000001        // 15 SysTick

And then runtime you can fill CODE not a vector, at 0x20000000.

I point these options out because there is no one hard and fast rule for how a companies sandbox solution(s) will be designed.   Even if VTOR can be changed does not automatically mean that the vendor is going to use that solution.

Not using libraries means to me, doing your own linker script and bootstrap as well as application.  And as a result you are in control and can easily see how to solve this.  If you are doing a hybrid and using someone elses bootstrap, then you need to understand their solution and adapt to it or modify it.

Comment: I am surprised that you put so much effort into this very good answer. Have you noticed that questions tagged stm32 are usually not upvoted or accepted by the OPs? I answer them, but without too much effort. You have my UV

Comment: I had not noticed an stm32 connection.  seems to me to be the leading consumer of cortex-ms, I have bought a countless number of them at this point and made many breakout boards to play with them.  Im a big fan.    It was not too bad I had a qemu example and I had a systick example already I just had to merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

> how does it work?

The stm32 HAL libraries *if you use them* contain a vector table installed at a specific memory location https://github.com/MaJerle/stm32fxxx-hal-libraries/blob/1feae687f99552832ff82ede6558d5266eec6201/00-HAL_DRIVERS/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Source/Templates/gcc/startup_stm32f030xc.s#L138 which then forward instruction at a specific address to a function named `Systick_Handler`. That address is the address the microcontroller jumps to on interrupt.

> Is it because of the build-in libraries?

There are no "build-in" libraries. The only "build-in" is the microcontroller, which executes a specific instruction from a specific location on an interrupt. Refer to the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

Forst of all you do not program without libraries of startup code as something is calling the `main` function. So in this case find the file wich defines the **vector table** and place the address of your handler at the correct position.

1. I would start from reading the **documentation** (programming manual & reference manual) In the Programming manual you will find that at the beginning of the memory you need to have a vector table containing the addresses of the interrupt handlers.
   [image]

Using the **linker script** and some code (it can be assembler or C) you need to place the addresses of the handlers at the beginning of the address space.

2. Then you need to configure the systick.
3. Enable interrupts